# Is there a normal extension $L$ such that $\mathbb Q \subset \mathbb Q(\sqrt3) \subset L$ with cyclic $\text{Gal}(L/\mathbb Q) \cong \mathbb Z_4^+$

Tags: proof-verification, galois-theory

I am just beginning Galois and don't have much control over the material.

> Is there a normal extension $L$ such that $\mathbb Q \subset \mathbb Q(\sqrt3) \subset L$ with cyclic $\text{Gal}(L/\mathbb Q) \cong \mathbb Z_4^+$.

1. I already know that $\text{Gal}(\mathbb Q(\sqrt3)/\mathbb Q)$ consists the identity and the automorphism such that $\mp \sqrt3 \mapsto \pm \sqrt3$.
2. With $\text{Gal}(L/\mathbb Q) \cong \mathbb Z_5^\times \cong \mathbb Z_4^+$, we have one permutation of order $1$, one of order $2$, and two of order $4$.

So, these clues suggest that $L = \mathbb Q(\sqrt3, i)$.  But according to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1108583/galois-extension-of-mathbbq-with-galois-group-mathbbz-4-mathbbz-that), such an extension does not exist.  Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: It seems that $\text{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3},i)/\mathbb{Q}) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2^2$, not $\mathbb{Z}_4$

Comment: you pulled out $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 3,i)$ out of thin air with no argumentation whatsoever about its Galois group

Comment: You're right; $\text{Gal}(\mathbb Q(\sqrt3, i) / \mathbb Q) \cong \mathbb Z_2^2$.  TY ....

Comment: There’s no such field, but it seems to me that proving this involves relatively delicate arithmetic considerations — primes in $\Bbb Z[\sqrt3]$ etc. (In other words, there’s no room for the proof in this margin.) Maybe someone has a simple proof, though. You should try the same with $\sqrt2$, where there *is* such a field.

Comment: What about $\mathbb Q(i\sqrt3)$?